# How to identify and mount filesystem of partition type 63 - Unixware

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How can I identify and mount the filesystem from a old Unix machine ?

- Using file to the dd image simply reports `X86 boot block`.
- Using `testdisk` and checking the bootblack I get multiple entries called `Solaris Home` but `testdisk` is unable to access the filesystem structure.
- I have the idea of being with VXFs but calling VXFS in mount reports same error.
- Tried to use `kpartx` in order to access only the "inside" partition but still with no success.
- Using checked the first bytes (in the loopback partition mapped from kpartx ) with 
  hexdump /dev/mapper/loop0p4 -C | head -n 1 
  resulting in

  > 00000000  fa ea 06 00 c0 07 8c c8  8e c0 8e d8 8e d0 66 bc  |..............f.|

Tried mount with UFS, Minix, VXFs and several others with no success.

Comment: The original data *could* be damaged. Considering this is essentially guess-work, details of the original machine might be of use here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hex dump, this could be an [SCO OpenServer system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO_OpenServer). And [this info](http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec1linuxfs.html) might help. The best & most realistic answer I found [is on the “Unix & Linux Stack Exchange” site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52046):

> 1. Connect and mount the drive on an existing SCO system or Boot the hard drive into SCO OpenServer (or SCO rescue disk if you have one)
>      and then copy your data off via network or removable media. I realize
>      that this is not what you were asking but may be the shortest route
>      depending on what you have available. You may be able to find a copy
>      of SCO on Ebay if you don't have one (finding compatible hardware may
>      be interesting).
> 2. Get Linux to mount the SCO HTFS filesystem [via these instructions](http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec1linuxfs.html).